# Word break on whitespace pre

Tags: html, css

Is there a solution to use `word-break` on `white-space: pre`?

I got a list like this, all came from `data base`, and I can't change it to `ul li`, but I want to show up like that so I then used `white-space: pre`, but it does not break words.

```css
td {
    white-space: pre;
    word-break: break-word;
}

table {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>list</th>
<td>
1.testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
2.hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
3.hurayhurayhurayhurayhurayhurayhuray
4.testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or use something like `white-space: pre` to break each item to new line with breaking words?

Comment: Why can't you format it using an `<ol>`? That would be far more semantic.

Comment: @BenM it all came from `database` it's not just a one entry

Comment: And? Why does that mean you can't format it as you wish?

Comment: i can change texts but it not translate `html` tags @BenM

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks

```css
td {
   word-break: break-word;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   -moz-white-space: pre-wrap;      
}

table {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>list</th>
<td>
1.testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
2.hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
3.hurayhurayhurayhurayhurayhurayhuray
4.testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox.  seems to work ok on chrome though.

Comment: @pedram I'm looking at "Run code snippet" right now in Firefox v50.0.2 and it's not working.  The long words don't wrap and extend out of the box.  not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: @andi you right, same here. but weird.. it works on my website !

Comment: FF needs prefixing. try `white-space: pre-wrap;` and `-moz-white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: @andi how about `overflow-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-all`? For now I can't test it by FF